# "External: SIGSEGV' exception from SetLength call

Tags: arrays, lazarus

[WaitFree Var code in assembler window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WNDT.png)
I get this exception when I set array length to 0 on a 3 dimensional dynamic array before exiting the program.  If I do not set it 0 and exit the application I get this exception at a different location in the assembler code.  I would like to know if anyone else has this problem with dynamic arrays.  I've also had it work on certain size dynamics arrays.  The size of the smallest array that causes the error dblArray(1000, 5, 21): array of array of array of double as are (1000, 25, 21), (1000, 27, 94), (1000, 28, 94), and (1000, 29, 94).  The arrays(1000, 18, 21) and (1000, 26, 94) exits successfully.  All arrays are double as described on the first array.  is setting length to 0 in on the first dimension sufficient to release memory on array or must all the dimensions be set to 0?  This exception is not trappable and cannot be stopped so the executable behaves erractically. The arrays themselves appear to be place holders existing entire life of the application.  They are not created or destroyed.  Is there any other way to declare them.  Most of the other questions involve some sort of exception are declaration error like wrong type of variable.  The implies to me the resource or array is tied up somehow as though application has disposed of it before the close procedure has executed.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of error is indicative of a heap corruption. Typically because you are writing beyond the range of an array. Those writes can corrupt the heap.

You will need to debug your program to find out which specific part of it is accessing out of bounds. Enable the range checking compiler option to make the compiler emit runtime code that verifies array access does not use out of bounds indices.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it and get back to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks Dave it worked after I fixed the range errors.  I'm annoyed I couldn't see the errors because the program appeared to work most of the time.   I had an index value of -1 on the dynamic arrays. I also had one where the dynamic array was not large enough.  I guess I expected Lazarus to catch the error, but it seems more like C in that regard.